# Android - Prompt Dialog window when touch on Notification

Tags: android, dialog, notifications

I am new to android application development. I am doing an application for my final year project.

My application will remind a user for an appointment. So far I manage to show the alert on notification bar on the appointment date.

My supervisor has requested to add a function, that, when a user tab on the notification bar, there will be a dialog window and show the details (Title of the appointment and the location).

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(context,YourActivityClassHere.class);
notifyIntent.setFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
//UNIQUE_ID if you expect more than one notification to appear
PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(SimpleNotification.this, UNIQUE_ID, 
            notifyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

1. Make the **PendingIntent** open up one of your Activities
2. Make that Activity completely transparent and open a Dialog.

IF you want to open an Activity from notification click event:

Assuming that **notif** is your **Notification** object:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), ActivityToStart.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, notificationIntent, 0);
notif.contentIntent = contentIntent;
```

For other assistance you can view this [sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Notifications/Notify1/), it will help you:

Comment: sure...and let me know soon...@@@

Comment: i should make a new activity? or i can add this into the alert activity?

Comment: yaah, dear you have to create your own new activity, I have named that as "YourActivityClassHere" in my answer.

Comment: hi, what if i want to open one of the activity of my app by pressing on the notification?

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidNotifications/article.html
Now don't ask me , how to create an object in JAVA....!!!:(