# android - How to show a dialog when click on notification

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-dialog

I get notification in my application through BroadcastReceiver, The question is , How can I parse data to an activity and make a dialog with the received data ?

this is my code but when I click on the notification , nothing happens :

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        notificationIntent.setData(Uri.parse(link));
        PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0, notificationIntent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        Notification myNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setAutoCancel(false).setLargeIcon(remote_picture)
                .setContentTitle(onvan).setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
                .setContentText(msg).setContentIntent(pending).build();
        notificationManager.notify(1, myNotification);
```

I've some variablese like link , msg, onvan that contains my data and I need to send these variables to an activity and make a dialog .

How can I do so ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9751134/3514144

Comment: use activity as dialogue http://stackoverflow.com/a/1979631/1168654

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(context,YourActivityClassHere.class);
notifyIntent.setFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
//UNIQUE_ID if you expect more than one notification to appear
PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(SimpleNotification.this, UNIQUE_ID, 
            notifyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

just make the **PendingIntent** open up one of your Activities and have your Activity be complete transparent and just open a Dialog.

EDIT: IF you want to open an Activity from notification click event:

Assuming that **notif** is your **Notification** object:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), ActivityToStart.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, notificationIntent, 0);
notif.contentIntent = contentIntent;
```

For more detail visit here.  [Android - Prompt Dialog window when touch on Notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14100004/android-prompt-dialog-window-when-touch-on-notification)

Answer (score 1):

You can send data from your notification to another `Activity` using method `putExtra` and put this

```
PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT));
```

inplace of this

```
PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0, notificationIntent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`
```